# what's going on in parseFloat('number').toFixed(2)?

Tags: javascript

What's going on in this method

```
parseFloat('123.234').toFixed(2);
```

How to create such functions on the results of which we can call other functions? Can someone provide the internal structure of such methods? Is this method chaining?

Comment: this may be of interest: http://phrogz.net/js/classes/ExtendingJavaScriptObjectsAndClasses.html

Comment: this, too: http://blog.getify.com/2010/02/simulated-chaining-in-javascript/

Comment: You are just calling the `toFixed` method of the result return by `parseFloat`. As long as you know what kind of value is returned, you can access any property of it. E.g. I know that `getElementById` returns a DOM node, so I can do: `var name = document.getElementById('foo).nodeName;`. There is nothing special what these methods are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indeed is method chaining. `parseFloat` returns a `Number object`, which has a method `toFixed`.

This is a basic example to show you how it works:

```
function Construct(){
   this.method1 = function(){
     return this;
   };
   this.method2 = function(){
     alert('called method2');
     return this;
   };
   this.method3 = function(){
     alert('method3: I am not chainable');
   };
}

var instance = new Construct;
instance.method1().method2().method3(); 
  //=> alerts 'called method2' and 'method3: I am not chainable'
```